# TF84033: Team foundation was unable to modify the list

Tags: azure-devops

I am using excel to bulk modify work items in vsts. After adding a list, when I press Refresh in teams addin, i get this error.

I have tried in new files and fieerent machines but the error continues to appear.

TF84033: Team foundation was unable to modify the list

Seeing the below error in Microsoft Excel build 1806. What could be the reason any sugeestion?

[image]

Comment: R u trying to import/publish TFS info[Workitems/Test scripts/...] through Excel?

Comment: It would help if you describe what you're trying to do step by step

Comment: Thanks for the response folks. I have office installed. I added a new list from TFS using Teams TFS addin. The moment I refresh it I get this error. Any way to get around this?

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal What the URL did you used to connect to the server? And what did you do with the exported work items in excel or related work item in VSTS web page?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I mentioned above, the list comes fine. The connection url was my vso url. and it was working fine till some time back. The list gets added well - the refresh fails.

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal Does it happens for all queries or a certain query?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT  All queries

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal What's the MS excel version do you use? And can you publish the local changes to VSTS work items in Excel?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I am in inner ring and have the latest excel build.

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal What if you create a simple query (such as query for work item type is Task) and export to excel? And can you also share the screen shots for the query and the excel result here?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT we are going in circles. I have given all diagnostics and the build versions as well. Not sure how the screen shots will help when I have shared the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
I have a TFS List with added formulas.
on the list with no added formula there is no problem.[Spoiler alert: The formulas were not the issue]
I don't have the solution just yet.
but the workaround is:
Go to the top of the list and delete all the rows except the first data row.
after that go to the team tab and click refresh.
The list will be refreshed with out an error.
the formulas will be filled too.
That is the work around I've used.

I hope it helps.
Regards, Alex

Comment: Well, I just found the answer... At least for the problem I have, it may work for you.

Comment: The problem is that one field has too much data, that is why when you delete the rows the offending field gets deleted and the upload can take place...what I did is to deleted half the list and checked if I could refresh the list, since I couldn't, then I erase half of what I had... and so on until I found which row had the problem... then it was easy to find the offending field. I went to TFS and copied the info to a notepad and attached it, and erased the data. No problem after that. Regards, Alex

Comment: Hey Alex, I cant delete the top row which has the query info. excel doesnt allow me to

Comment: Hi Abhishek: No, you don't want to erase the first 3 rows. you need to erase from row 4 on. So you leave one row of data and formulas etc. then you refresh. But that is a workaround (that worked for me) it is not the real fix. if you do it make sure you have a back up of the file :-) )

Comment: Having said that, it is much better to try to find what is the field that has too much data. Regards, Alex